# '-' is not a valid resource name character

Tags: java, android

I entered admob banner ID to my android project. Inside the strings.xml file.

When I build a apk it gives me error
*'-' is not a valid resource name character*

```
<string name =ca-app-pub-2345567777/6578687568"></string>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try underscore instead of hyphen

Comment: The `name` is the value you use to reference the string resource in your code (i.e. `R.string.admob_id`). The actual value goes inside the angled brackets

Answer (score 2):

You should use string like this.

```
<string name ="admob_id">ca-app-pub-2345567777/6578687568</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this -:

```
<string name="advertisment_key">ca-app-pub-2345567777/6578687568</string>
```

Instead of-:

```
<string name =ca-app-pub-2345567777/6578687568"></string>
```